# How to check if document exist if firestore database collection or not in Flutter application?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How to check whether a document exists in the firestore collection or not in flutter application?
I tried various examples already available on SO, but they seem to be deprecated. Please advise the solution

```
DocumentReference ref2 = Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(currentUserID);
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's helpful to show and explain what did try that didn't work the way you expect.  We need to be able to see if you were possibly doing something wrong, so it can be corrected.  The usual methods of checking if a document exists are not deprecated - it's been the same for a long time.

Comment: @PeterHaddad done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if a document exists, you need to use `get()` method which is used to retrieve the data from the document, then you can use the property `exists`:

```
    Firestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .document(currentUserID)
        .get()
        .then((doc) {
      if(doc.exists) {
        print("exists");
      } else {
        print("doesnt exists");
      }
    });
```